# Browse files system and show image in span using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on ASP.NET MVC3 application using razor view. I'm trying to create a simple custom image gallery with delete/upload options. All the logic is inside a `@HTML.BeginForm` so data is submitted to the server only when the whole form is submit, until then I want the user to be able to add/remove images without making calls to the server. In fact the user will see `Delete` and `Upload` links but both of these won't have any impact on my back end logic until the whole form is submitted.

That's why I want to let the user browse the files system and add/remove different images, but when he selects image I want to show it in my `span` tag and that's all.

I have limited amount of images that can be attached to a form so for uploading images I have this :

```
@for (var i = ViewBag.PictureCount; i < Model[0].MCS_Documents.MaxPicCount; i++)
    { 
        <span class="document-image-frame">
        <a href="#" class="upload-document-image">Upload Image</a>
        </span>
    }
```

and via jQuery I want to show the selected image inside this `span` but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Even very simple I have this:

```
$('upload-document-image').click(function () {
    //???    
    });
```

When the user clicks "Upload Image" I want to open a File Dialog window and when he selects an image I want to show it, but no interact with the server.

Comment: You can get base64 encoded content from file and assign it to img.src. But you will need to use Html5 file api, so it will not be supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved without interaction with the server only if the client browser supports the [`HTML 5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). So as the documentation shows you could start by adding a file input field to your view:

```
@for (var i = ViewBag.PictureCount; i < Model[0].MCS_Documents.MaxPicCount; i++)
{ 
    <span class="document-image-frame">
        <a href="#" class="upload-document-image">Upload Image</a>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this)" />
    </span>
}
```

and then we could wire the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.upload-document-image').click(function() {
        $(this).next('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');
        return false;
    });
});

function handleFiles(fileInput) {
    var files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.classList.add("obj");
        img.file = file;
        $(fileInput).after(img);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) { 
            return function(e) { 
                aImg.src = e.target.result; 
            }; 
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }    
}
```

Here's a [`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/jRUeQ/).

If the client browser doesn't support the HTML 5 File API you have no choice but to upload the image to the server, and the point a dynamically generated `<img>` tag to it so that the preview can be displayed.

Comment: Thanks. The target browser isIE9, gonna try your suggestion but I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: No, it ain't gonna work. IE9 doesn't support the HTML 5 File API. So don't waste your time.